# Google Chrome logs out after Browser Close

Tags: google-chrome, logout

I am on a fresh new install.
I downloaded Google Chrome from the offical webiste and installed it by double clicking

`google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

When I log in into my Google Account to sync bookmarks etc everything works fine and syncs properly.

As soon as I close Chrome my User gets logged out and I have a little text beside my icon in the top saying "Paused".

I tried to:

`sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable`

`rm ~/.config/google-chrome`

`rm ~/.cache/google-chrome`

But after a reinstall the problem still persisted.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I fixed it myself. I somehow had in my google account under:

Delete Cookies from `xx` after Browser restart

```
accounts.google.com
```

Removed that. Works now.

Comment: I fixed it on my father's computer when it suddenly appeared to behave like the question. I blamed him although he said he didn't do anything special in the settings. Today I suddenly came through this issue too... He works on Ubuntu and me on mac OS. I guess the last Google Chrome update is related in some way.